# 19.04 will not boot from HD nor USB

Tags: boot, 19.04

I had a fully functional 19.04 machine until I rebooted today. Now the machine boots to a blinking cursor on a black screen. Since pressing the power button results in an immediate shutdown, it appears nothing has loaded.

I see there are a couple of other posts regarding 10.04 and booting. However, I can't try any of the suggestions as these there methods all go to a blinking cursor
- booting from HD
- holding left shift while booting
- booting from a 19.04 USB

System is a Dell 8900 with NVIDA graphics, i7 processor. Had been running 18.04 without problem for a year. 19.04 was installed as a fresh install, not upgrade.

The same thing happened a few days ago but I was able to hold down left shift, get into the utility (not sure what it is called), updated GRUB and then it rebooted.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want to boot from external media you need to open UEFI settings and use the boot override or the one-time boot menu. It's an hardware characteristic/feature independent of the installed OS.

Comment: Thanks @GabrielaGarcia, I had already done that.

Comment: After a few more tries to boot from USB it succeeded. I exited without doing anything. Then I changed the boot options so the only choice was 'Hard drive' which in my case is the Ubuntu 19.04 install. System booted just fine. A bit of a mystery going on.

Comment: It has been 9 days since I disabled all Gnome extensions and I have experienced no problems since. Looks likely it was an extension problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with an nvidia card and Ubuntu 19.04 on a desktop. Workarounds that I found were:

- When at the screen with the blinking cursor, press Ctrl+Alt+F2 and then Ctrl+Alt+F1 (or some variation of this until the login screen appears).
- Use the lightdm package to handle logins instead of gdm (however, I found a minor issue with the mouse cursor size with a 4K display when I used this solution).
- Edit /lib/systemd/system/gdm.service and comment out the ExecStartPre line with a '#' and then add ExecStartPre=sleep 5